# In mapbox can you only disable the ability to zoom in?

Tags: mapbox

Im writing a map where the user can only zoom in to a specific level before having to click on a marker, I know you can disable zooming in and out with:

```
    // Disable drag and zoom handlers.
    map.touchZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

    // Disable tap handler, if present.
    if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
```

but I would like the user to still be able to zoom out once they hit the specific zoom level. Is there a way to only disable zoom in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the minZoom and maxZoom options when you create your map. This way the user can only zoom in so far but can still zoom out.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'accessToken';
L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapId', {zoomControl: false, attributionControl: false, minZoom: 5});
```